# .htaccess deny all subfolder in given folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a simple folder tree:

```
orders
  |-I-Cant-Predict-The-Name
  |-I-Cant-Predict-The-Name-2
  |-I-Cant-Predict-The-Name-3
  .
  .
  .
  |-I-Cant-Predict-The-Name-XYZ
```

I need a .htaccess that denies access for all subfolders in orders folder and any file in them too. Also I can't predict the file types in those folders.
I plan to access the files with PHP (and only with PHP so no direct links) from an admin area with `file_get_contents()`, but I can't let anyone to guess the folders and files as they are private (despite the fact I use hash with a salt for folder names so it is hard to guess).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write this in you .htaccess:

`deny from all`

After this you'll get error 403 when you try to access these sub-folders.

Comment: OMG that easy? This is a huge facepalm on my side, I always thought deny from all is for the given folder we are in and not for subfolders. Thank you. I accept this as soon as the system let me to do it.